# My Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
`

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {TailwindProvider} from 'react-native-tailwindcss';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function App(){
  return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <TailwindProvider>
     <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component=
        {HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
     </TailwindProvider>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

`
```

I checked whether I properly imported the HomeScreen component in the App.js file, using the correct file path and syntax (i.e., import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen').

Still getting the same error